# Scanner doesn't stop to get input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

Alright, very noob question. I'm making a CLI app that lets users design surveys. First they enter the question, then the number of choices and the choices. I'm using a Scanner to get input, and for some reason it lets the user enter most things, but not the text of the question. Code snippet below.

```
String title = "";
Question[] questions;
int noOfQuestions = 0;
int[] noOfChoices;
Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the title of the survey: ");
title = entry.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter the number of questions: ");
noOfQuestions = entry.nextInt();
noOfChoices = new int[noOfQuestions];
questions = new Question[noOfQuestions];
for (int i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {
    questions[i] = new Question();
}
for (int i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {

    System.out.println("Please enter the text of question " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    questions[i].questionContent = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of choices for question " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    questions[i].choices = new String[entry.nextInt()];
    for (int j = 0; j < questions[i].choices.length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter choice " + (j + 1) + " for question " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        questions[i].choices[j] = entry.nextLine(); 

    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure this is all the relevant code?  Do you not read in "noOfQuestions" from the Scanner as well?

Comment: Yep, there's some more code between Scanner declaration and the for loop. I left them out because it'd make the quoted code too long. Adding them back in right now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason I asked about whether you read `noOfQuestions` from the Scanner is because `Scanner.nextInt()` does not consume the delimiter (e.g. the new line).

That means that the next time you call `nextLine()`, you will just get an empty String from the previous `readInt()`.

```
75\nQuestion 1: What is the square route of pie?
^ position before nextInt()

75\nQuestion 1: What is the square route of pie?
  ^ position after nextInt()

75\nQuestion 1: What is the square route of pie?
    ^ position after nextLine()
```

My suggestion is to just read by line, always with `nextLine()`, and then parse afterwards using `Integer.parseInt()`.

If that's the route you take, there's little need for a Scanner at all; you can just accept a BufferedReader.

Comment: The alternative is to pair each nextInt() with a nextLine() whose result you discard, but that gets messy.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [nextLine()](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) says *Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.* Might explain the behavior you are seeing. Just to verify you can add a sysout and print the value of title after the `title = entry.nextLine()` and see what value it is holding

If you want to read a complete line from the input you might want to use the [InputStreamReader combination with BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

Comment: Yeah, but I used nextLine several times, and it's only skipped at the "question text" part. It didn't skip at the "enter title" part, for instance.